# Python / Import N files by their names and path

Tags: python, file, import

I'm looking for dynamicaly importing a number N of python files by their names and path as string.
Then, in my main.py file I Want to be able to call every functions of each imported files.
Do you have any advice to give me ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome! This post is a bit light on detail. Why are you trying to do this? (E.g., if it's for testing, there are lots of packages for that!) Do you want to take n random files from anywhere on your computer's disk in general, or in a more specific place?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to organize my code with differents subfolders and pythons files. 

Here is the code structure:
https://pastebin.com/raw/zCV87yP9

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Are you trying to use Python to rearrange the files rather than doing it by hand? Or are you implicitly asking how to do an import (e.g., define `f` in file1.py and use `f` in file2.py)?